# I'm new in Solidity. Stuck at Cryptozombies Lesson 2 Chapter 13

Tags: solidity

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. It doesn't let me go to the next chapter and when pasting in IDE, it gives me a parser error saying '(' expected got identifier.

Here's my code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

import "./zombiefactory.sol";

contract KittyInterface {
  function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view returns (
    bool isGestating,
    bool isReady,
    uint256 cooldownIndex,
    uint256 nextActionAt,
    uint256 siringWithId,
    uint256 birthTime,
    uint256 matronId,
    uint256 sireId,
    uint256 generation,
    uint256 genes
  );
}
contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

  address ckAddress = 0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d;
  KittyInterface kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);

  function feedAndMultiply(uint _zombieId, uint _targetDna, string memory _species) public {
    require(msg.sender == zombieToOwner[_zombieId]);
    Zombie storage myZombie = zombies[_zombieId];
    _targetDna = _targetDna % dnaModulus;
    uint newDna = (myZombie.dna + _targetDna) / 2;
    if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_species)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("kitty"))) {
    newDna = newDna - newDna % 100 + 99;
    _createZombie("NoName", newDna);
    }
    
  function feedOnKitty(uint _zombieId, uint _kittyId) public {
    uint kittyDna;
    (,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(_kittyId);
    feedAndMultiply(_zombieId, kittyDna, "kitty");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot a closing bracket to end your feedAndMultiply function

Answer (score 0):

Future note,
if you look carefully, when you press check answer it will highlight the mistake with a more intensive red collor.